# Handle XML-object in php

Tags: php, xml

This is the XML i get on my request to a server. It is a XML with some information about the current user. I want to check if it is more than one respons with **TotalNumberOfResults**. If that one is bigger than one i want to iterate and find the ****Results->ResultItem->ResultType = Person****.

Each Result excict in a **ResultItem**. If it matches i want to pick rest of the information of that ResultItem(**FirstName, LastName, Zip, etc**).

***This is the XML i get back from the request:***

```
<SearchResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://secret.link”>
<ExtensionData/>
<Results>
<ResultItem>
<ExtensionData/>
<Addresses>
<Address_Search>
<ExtensionData/>
<AddressType>Visiting</AddressType>
<City>Oslo</City>
<Country>Norway</Country>
<FormattedAddress>The whole adress</FormattedAddress>
<HouseNumber>13</HouseNumber>
<MunicipalityCode>1234</MunicipalityCode>
<Street>Streetadress</Street>
<StreetId>12313</StreetId>
<Zip>1234</Zip>
</Address_Search>
</Addresses>
<BirthDate xsi:nil="true"/>
<Collection>Contacts</Collection>
<ContactPoints>
<ContactPoint_Search>
<ExtensionData/>
<Address>2312313</Address>
<ContactPointType>Mobile</ContactPointType>
<IsMain>true</IsMain>
</ContactPoint_Search>
<ContactPoint_Search>
<ExtensionData/>
<Address>mail@mail.com</Address>
<ContactPointType>Email</ContactPointType>
<IsMain>false</IsMain>
</ContactPoint_Search>
<ContactPoint_Search>
<ExtensionData/>
<Address>123123</Address>
<ContactPointType>Landline</ContactPointType>
<IsMain>false</IsMain>
</ContactPoint_Search>
<ContactPoint_Search>
<ExtensionData/>
<Address/>
<ContactPointType>Mobile</ContactPointType>
<IsMain>false</IsMain>
</ContactPoint_Search>
</ContactPoints>
<FirstName>Name</FirstName>
<ItemId>123123</ItemId>
<LastName>Name’sen</LastName>
<ResultType>Person</ResultType>
</ResultItem>
</Results>
<TotalNumberOfResults>1</TotalNumberOfResults>
</SearchResponse>
```

***This is some of the server-php i have with this request:***

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_file($the_url_to_the_request);
            $result = [];

            if ($xml->TotalNumberOfResults > 1) {
                foreach ($xml as $key => $value) {
                    if ($value->Results->ResultItem->ResultType == "Person") {
                        //var_dump("It's a match");
                        //var_dump($value->Results->ResultItem->ResultType);exit;
                        $result = array("Name" => $value->Results->ResultItem->FirstName . "", "Surname" => $value->Results->ResultItem->LastName . "",  "ZIP" => $value->Results->ResultItem->Addresses->Address_Search->Zip . "", "By" => $value->Results->ResultItem->Addresses->Address_Search->City . "", "City" => $value->Results->ResultItem->Addresses->Address_Search->City . "");
                        echo($_GET['callback'] . "(" . json_encode($result) . ");");
                    }
                }

            }else{
                $result = array("Name" => $xml->Results->ResultItem->FirstName . "", "Surname" => $xml->Results->ResultItem->LastName . "",  "ZIP" => $xml->Results->ResultItem->Addresses->Address_Search->Zip . "", "City" => $xml->Results->ResultItem->Addresses->Address_Search->City . "", "By" => $xml->Results->ResultItem->Addresses->Address_Search->City . "");                
                echo($_GET['callback'] . "(" . json_encode($result) . ");");
            }
```

***The question: It's working just fine with one result, but nothing happends with multiple results.***

Comment: You have to change element collection you iterate with `foreach` loop. It should be `$xml->Results`, not `$xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change element collection you iterate with `foreach` loop. It should be `$xml->Results`, not `$xml`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($the_url_to_the_request);
$result = [];
if ($xml->TotalNumberOfResults > 1) {
    foreach ($xml->Results as $key => $value) {
        if ($value->ResultItem->ResultType == "Person") {
            //var_dump("It's a match");
            //var_dump($value->ResultItem->ResultType);exit;
            $result = array("Name" => $value->ResultItem->FirstName . "", "Surname" => $value->ResultItem->LastName . "",  "ZIP" => $value->ResultItem->Addresses->Address_Search->Zip . "", "By" => $value->ResultItem->Addresses->Address_Search->City . "", "City" => $value->ResultItem->Addresses->Address_Search->City . "");
            echo($_GET['callback'] . "(" . json_encode($result) . ");");
        }
    }
}
else {
    $result = array("Name" => $xml->Results->ResultItem->FirstName . "", "Surname" => $xml->Results->ResultItem->LastName . "",  "ZIP" => $xml->Results->ResultItem->Addresses->Address_Search->Zip . "", "City" => $xml->Results->ResultItem->Addresses->Address_Search->City . "", "By" => $xml->Results->ResultItem->Addresses->Address_Search->City . "");
    echo($_GET['callback'] . "(" . json_encode($result) . ");");
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, why didnt i see that, thank you

Comment: @simonkaspers1 You could choose this answer as "accepted" as well if it solve your problem

Comment: i had to wait a few minutes

Comment: look at the code. will it behave differently or the same if TotalNumberOfResults is larger than one? What do you think? How much of the code can be removed without changing behavior?

Comment: @hakre I have changed the code to handle TotalNumberOfResults==1 first, because most of the results is one. That is to prevent unnecessary forlooping. Will that be good for the responstime?

Comment: it will make no difference but will cost you some fractions of a millisecond. for the loop it's so much whatever if it loops zero, one or n times. that means, all you need is the loop because it is already the if. so the if is superfluous and you can remove some lines of code. which is comfortable because then you have one point of output only (very useful).